# What do I call a unit vector parallel to a coordinate axis?

Tags: terminology, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

What do I call an arbitrary element of this set of vectors?
$$
\begin{align*}
\{&\langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle, \\
&\langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle, \\ 
&\langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle, \\ 
&\langle -1, 0, 0 \rangle, \\
&\langle 0, -1, 0 \rangle, \\
&\langle 0, 0, -1 \rangle \} \\
\end{align*}
$$

The significance is that this set contains every unit vector which lies on a cubical grid (is in $\mathbb{Z}^3$, as are all sums of elements). In particular, they are all possible directions of motion to adjacent grid points.

It differs from the [standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) in including the inverse of each basis vector.

The context is computer game/graphics programming.

Comment: The axis-aligned unit vectors?

Comment: Rahul Narain: Ding. Perfect. Make that an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call them the axis-aligned unit vectors.

Comment: This is especially good as “axis-aligned” is a common term in the field (“axis-aligned bounding boxes”).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep to just comment but is there any reason why you couldn't just call them the unit vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ ?

Comment: Here’s a reason: $\mathbb{Z}^3$ isn’t a vector space, since you can’t define scalar multiplication on it. I also think that doesn't flow well in the sort of context it will be used in, e.g. “`// Return a rotation code to bring the +z vector to match the given unit vector in Z^3`”

Comment: That's true. $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is a well defined [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so is relatively unambiguous as far as terminology goes though perhaps it may be of the wrong 'type' for computational purposes

Answer (score 0):

Typically we name the unit vectors $\hat{i}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$,  $\hat{j}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\hat{k}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

As for $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ we simply call it $-\hat{i}$. The same applys for the remaining two vectors.

For further reading you can visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).

Comment: I am looking for a single name which applies to any element of this set, not names for each of the six.